# How to get a current symbol table

Tags: python, scope, symbol-table

In [python](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/symtable.html) we can use the following:

```
symtable.symtable(code,file,compile type)
```

But is it possible to get a `symtable` object a current executable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable code itself carries that information.  See the [`inspect` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html), but code objects have `co_names` and `co_varnames`, for example.

Comment: So if we cannot get access to a symbol table of current executable code directly it isn't clear why does symtable object type is introduced? Is it for checking of the specifiec  symbol tables `code`?

Comment: It is there for the parser and compiler to build the bytecode.